# Why is array duplicating itself in express?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, express

I don't even know where to start....

Here is my code...

```
    const request = require("request");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let posts = [];

function sort(postsCollection, type, direction){
    let target = postsCollection[type];
    let swapp = false,
        n = postsCollection.length - 1,
        x = postsCollection;
    do {
        swapp = false;
        for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(x[i][type] < x[i+1][type]){
                let temp = x[i];
                x[i+1] = temp;
                swapp = true;
            }
        }
        n--;
    } while (swapp);
    return x;
}

function postExists(posts, post){
    if(posts.indexOf(post) == -1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    buildPostsCollection(options, url){
        //posts = [];
        if(!options || !url){
            return "Error: No options or URL given";
        }

        options.tags.forEach((tag) => {
           const newUrl = `${url}?tag=${tag}`;

           request.get(newUrl, (err, res, body) => {
               let target = JSON.parse(body)['posts'];

               Object.keys(target).forEach((key) => {
                   if(postExists(posts, target[key]) == false){
                       posts.push(target[key]);
                   }
                   /*
                   if(!(posts.includes(target[key]))){
                       posts.push(target[key]);
                   }
                   */
               })
           });
        });
        return posts;
    },
    orderPostsCollection(postsCollection, sortType, direction){
        if(!sortType && !direction){
            return postsCollection;
        }

        if(sortType) {
            return sort(postsCollection, sortType, direction);
        }else if(direction){
            return sort(postsCollection, false, direction);
        }
    }
};
```

I don't know if its me or what.. But when I call this code through the api server I just made it duplicates itself over and over.... IE.. The posts array does not disappear, it just adds to itself everytime the page is refreshed..

Also I should add that, I had issues even keeping the posts array in existence across the functions.. I can't `array.push` to it unless its a global variable. And for some reason my duplicate checking functions do not work on it..

Comment: you defined posts at global level. define it in your request handler callback

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you explain that a bit more please? 

The request handler call back is.... `buildPostsCollection` ?

Comment: at line 4 you have let posts = []; 
you should move this line to the very first line of buildPostCollection function. you already comment out the posts. remove that and write let posts = [];

Comment: Moving posts[] to buildPostCollection, when returned, is undefined..

Comment: Just found out that `request(url, callback)` the function is async.. So my function was returning data before it was ready.

I was stuck for so long and tried to find out that question all night. There is no documentation that it is async....